# Why is alert is working only for a single time when not in function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
document.querySelector('html').onclick = function() {
    alert('Hy');
}
```

works each time I click on the webpage displaying a dialogue box.

but if I were to remove function declaration and instead write

```
document.querySelector('html').onclick = alert('Hey');
```

it works only for once.

I don't understand this because I am asking javascript to alert by Hey each time I click on the webpage but it does the same only for once.
What effect does function declaration having on this snippet of code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between a function and the result of calling a function. In the second case, you're running the `alert` function immediately, and then setting the `onclick` to its result (which isn't a function and doesn't do anything useful).

Answer (score 0):

Because what this does:

```
document.querySelector("html").onclick = alert("Hey");
```

It runs the code `alert("Hey")`, then sets the `onclick` of the element to the *return value* of `alert("hey")`. This will only work as a proper event handler if `alert("Hey")` returns a function. It doesn't:

```js
console.log(alert("Hey"));
```

So you need to attach a function or function reference like so:

```js
document.body.onclick = () => alert("Hey");
```

```html
<p>Click Me</p>
```

The above works and is only a small addition to your wanted syntax - we're using ES6 arrow functions for this.